# Convertir la notación científica a numero en SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Tengo datos en Excel con este formato

**161131188211 161131188158**

Pero cuando importo con SSIS los datos en SQL Server, se guarda como **1.6113118821e + 011 1.6113118816e + 011**

Necesito guardar esos valores en un campo de tipo varchar ya que son IP. Intenté lo siguiente para convertir:

```
select LTRIM(STR(v.[IP], 30))
```

Y la salida que estoy obteniendo es la adición de otro valor, al valor original para todos los métodos, es decir:

**161131188210 161131188160**

Comment: Hola @Dani esta comunidad es en español por favor puedes traducir tu pregunta para que que sea bien recibida y poderte brindar una mejor ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Edita la pregunta utilizando el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/263252/edit), justo debajo de la pregunta.

Comment: El problema es que los guardaste en una columna float en vez de una columna varchar. Eso puede generar que haya pérdida de datos.

Comment: @LuisCazares yo tengo el valor guardado en un campo varchar, estoy creando en una consulta otro campo con un case, que cuando consiga el formato notación científica hagas el cast, ahi tengo el problema

Comment: El problema es que, si se guardó en el varchar con notación científica, ya hubo pérdida de información. Tienes que regresar al punto previo a que estuviera en notación científica y comenzar el proceso desde ahí.

Comment: @LuisCazares la información viene de un excel, ya viene con ese formato ya que la columna esta tipo texto luego con SSIS yo guardo esa información en sql server.

Comment: Hay 2 opciones. El valor está guardado como número, por lo que lo debes convertir a texto con la función `=TEXT(A1,"#")` antes de importarlo con SSIS, o el valor está guardado como texto y la información ya se perdió.

Answer (score 0):

Pues no hay una funcion directa pero puedes crear una propia,
por ejemplo crea una funcion y agrega el siguiente codigo:
--tu entrada sera @ipConExponente

```
    declare @ipConExponente char(20)='1.6113118816e + 011';


    Declare @NumerosTabla table
         (rowNum int, dato varchar(12))

    declare @direccion varchar(12)
    declare @exponente varchar(12)

    insert @NumerosTabla
    select  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by value desc), value   from string_split(@ipConExponente,'e')


    set @direccion= (select REPLACE( dato,'.','') from @NumerosTabla where rowNum=1)
    set @exponente =(select trim(Replace(dato,'+',''))  from @NumerosTabla where rowNum=2)


    select @direccion,@exponente

    ---salida de la funcion
    SELECT Left(@direccion+'0000', @exponente+1)
--el +1 es porque eliminamos el . pero se recorre un lugar despues de cada entrada.

    --entrada: '1.6113118816e + 011'; salida: 161131188160
```

Answer (score 0):

Se que es tarde mi respuesta pero tan solo con

```
LEFT(CONVERT(numeric(25), v.[IP] ),25)
```

Comment: Checa [answer], considera editar y explicar tu aporte

Answer (score -1):

tu tema pasa por la precisión de los datos. El tipo de datos float es un tipo de dato numérico de aproximación al igual que el tipo "`real`". Si buscar utilizar numéricos largos intenta utilizar `numeric` o `decimal` (o cual mejor te acomode dependiendo de su precision y escala). Como muestra la referencia de la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Guiate por la referencia de MSFT para los tipo de datos en SQL Server. [Data types (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

PD: También recuerda que el valor máximo del bigint es "9223372036854775807"

Saludos.

Comment: Hola esteban, probe con esto LTRIM(STR(v.[IP], 30)) y me redondea en los últimos dígitos, vale acotar que la columna en excel esta tipo texto.